# Class Inheritance Design with Generic Lists

Tags: c#

I am currently struggling with a class design involving generic lists:

Code says more than thousand words:

```
class Document
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; } = new List<Result>();
}

class Result
{
}

class SpecialDocument : Document
{
    public new List<SpecialResult> Results { get; } = new List<SpecialResult>();
}

class SpecialResult : Result
{
}
```

What I don't like of the current design is that `SpecialDocument.Results` hides `Document.Results`. If one has the `Document` view on a `SpecialDocument`, there are no results at all, even there could be the `Result` view of all `SpecialResult` elements.

What I would like to accomplish is:

```
SpecialDocument doc = new SpecialDocument();
doc.Results.Add(new SpecialResult());
Assert.AreEqual(1, (doc as Document).Results.Count); // Here my design obviously fails right now
```

... I'd like to accomplish that without loosing type safety (as that's actually the reason for `List<T>` not being covariant).

## Edit

I forgot to mention that `SpecialDocument` and `Document` actually need to have the same successor (or implement the same interface), such that they can coexist within one collection:

```
List<Document> documents = new List<Document>()
{
    new Document(),
    new SpecialDocument()
};
```

Comment: Couldnt you make `Document` generic `where T : Result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is acceptable for `IDocument.Results` to be of type `IEnumerable<Result>` instead of `IList<Result>`, this will work.

The `Result` property must be typed this way due to co-variance / contra-variance rules.

Code is based on @Kyle B's excellent answer

```
void Main()
{

    IDocument doc = new SpecialDocument();

    //I added AddResult() to the interface to allow adding results, instead of calling Add() directly on the list.
    doc.AddResult(new SpecialResult());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, doc.Results.Count);

    // prooving that the items can be added to a list, and that list can handle all the result types.
    var docs = new List<IDocument>();
    docs.Add(new Document());
    docs.Add(new SpecialDocument());
    var results = docs.SelectMany(d => d.Results)
    // results now contains all results from all documents
}

abstract class Document<T> : IDocument where T : Result
{
    public List<T> Results { get; } = new List<T>();

    IEnumerable<Result> IDocument.Results => Results;

    void IDocument.AddResult(Result result)
    {
        this.Results.Add((T)result);
    }
}

abstract class Result
{
}

class Document : Document<Result>
{
}

class SpecialDocument : Document<SpecialResult>
{
}

class SpecialResult : Result
{
}

interface IDocument
{
    IEnumerable<Result> Results { get; }
    AddResult(Result result);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to take your specific unit test requirements in to account.

Comment: you have a cat as your icon and I have a dog.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried generics?

```
abstract class Document<T> where T : Result
{
    public List<T> Results { get; } = new List<T>();
}

abstract class Result
{
}

class SpecialDocument : Document<SpecialResult>
{
}

class SpecialResult : Result
{
}
```

`SpecialDocument` will automatically instantiate `List<SpecialResult>`.

Comment: Good idea, but then `SpecialDocument` is not derived from `Document` anymore, right? So one cannot do a cast like `doc as Document` for `SpecialDocument doc`...

Comment: @ManuelFaux That is currrect.  The typical solution is to create a non-generic `IDocument` interface that `Document<T>` implements.  That will allow you to put any kind of `Document<T>` derived class in to an `IDocument doc` variable.  You could also use an `abstract`, non-generic, `Document` class as the base class for `Document<T>` for the same purpose.

Comment: @BradleyUffner And is `Results` part of the interface specification in that case? Could one access `Results` from the `IDocument` point of view?

Comment: Yes, you can have it as part of the interface or base-class, but unfortunately, It'll have to be typed as `Result` (since that's what `T` is constrained to).  You won't be able to get the specific `Result` sub-class.  It will still be the correct type as far as polymorphism is concerned, but it will be viewed though `Result`.  That may or may not be a problem for you, depending on what you want to *do* with `Result`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Could you maybe post your solution? `class Document<T> : IDocument where T : Result` does not compile with `IDocument` containing `List<Result> Result`.

Comment: Let me see what I can do. I might be mistaken about `Result`, generics can be tricky to work out in your head sometimes.

Comment: Is `IDocument.Results` aceptable to be `IEnumerable<Result>` instead of `List<Result>`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner `ICollection` would be better, as `Count` is required (see `Assert` in question above), but I just see the problem: `IEnumerable<out T>` is variant, while `ICollection<T>` is not.

Comment: If all you need is `Count`, `IEnumerable<Result>` should work just fine. `Count` has explicit checks for if the base is a list type, and uses the optimized path (it doesn't actually iterate the collection). `List<>` and `Collection<>` won't work due to covariance / contravariance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take your unit-testing example in to account.